# What's the role of __irq in ARM System Programming?

Tags: arm, interrupt, bare-metal

I understand **__irq** is used to define *Interrupt Service Routine* function for ARM7(v4) architecture. But what changes does it make to the function?

As per [ARM Information Center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABICJBC.html):

> The __irq keyword enables a C or C++ function to be used as an interrupt routine.
>   __irq is a function qualifier. It affects the type of the function.

What kind of special treatment does ARM compiler provide to routines defined with **__irq** function qualifier??

Answer (score 2):

The compiler modifies the function exit/entry. This means adjusting lr, changing processor mode after return and saving & restoring registers that are not normally saved across function calls (normally r0-r3 and r12). Here is a short example:

```
void func()
{
    ...
}
```

Generated Assembler:

```
/* void func() */
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, lr}
    ...
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, lr}
    bx  lr
```

Same function as IRQ:

```
/* void __attribute__ ((interrupt ("IRQ"))) func() */
    sub lr, lr, #4
    stmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, ip, lr}
    ...
    ldmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, ip, pc}^
```

And as FIQ:

```
/* void __attribute__ ((interrupt ("FIQ"))) func() */
    sub lr, lr, #4
    stmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, lr}
    ...
    ldmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, pc}^
```

Note that the exact register list also depends on some external parameters such as the ABI.

Comment: So __irq takes care of (1)Restore Context and (2)Changing Processor to User Mode, when returning from ISR. What about ARM IRQ Re-enable??

Comment: @PraveenFelix Normally, the interrupt controller hardware disables interrupts upon entering and enables them upon exiting - as CPU changes to and from IRQ mode. (not sure if this is true for prioritized and nested interrupts).

Answer (score 1):

From [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

> > The compiler generates function entry and exit sequences suitable for use in an interrupt handler when this attribute is present.

I believe armcc does the same, you can use `objdump` to see the difference in the created binary.

From the page you referenced:

> > All corrupted registers except floating-point registers are preserved, not only those that are normally preserved under the AAPCS. The default AAPCS mode must be used.